# Sections with compact support

Tags: vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology

My question is: can anybody give me some examples of sections of a vector bundle with compact support?

I am under the impression there are two (related?) definitions of sections with compact support. One is analytic and one is algebraic. If this makes sense to you can you give me an example of both. Thanks
-Matt

Comment: Also, you can replace vector bundle with "sheaf" if you'd like.

Comment: In the analytic and algebraic world, either your variety is already proper so that a section with compact support is just a section, or your variety is not proper, in that case there is no section with compact support for a vector bundle. (For a sheaf, this is possible if the sheaf itself has proper support). Of course, in the continuous or differential world, there is a lot of sections with compact support. You can construct them the same way you would construct a function with compact support.